# Почему CORS ограничивает доступ к действию POST?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, cors

Всем привет. Есть сервис WEB API на .net core 2.1, в котором есть действие сохранения модели из формы:

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Save([FromForm] Document document)
    {
       //Некоторые действия.
    }
```

Так же есть клиентское приложение .net core mvc. Данные из формы к web api отправляет js. Код:

```
function SubmitForm(formData) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let form = new FormData(formData);
    xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:57803/api/save');
    xhr.onload = () => {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
            alert('Все норм!');
        }
        else {
            alert('Произошла ошибка!');
        }
    };
    xhr.send(form);
};
```

Но при отправке этого запроса в консоли выпадает ошибка: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:57803/api/save' from origin 'https://localhost:44377' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Хотя в классе StartUp web api указал следующее:

```
       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {

        app.UseCors(builder => { builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader(); });
  
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Так же стоит отметить, что есть метод удаления объекта в WEB API:

```
    [HttpDelete("[action]/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
    {
       //Некоторые действия.
    }
```

И в клиентском приложении следующий код:

```
        function deleteDoc(id, documentName) {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('DELETE', 'http://localhost:57803/api/delete/' + id);
        xhr.onload = () => {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                deleteRow(id, documentName);
            }
            else {
                errorDelete();   
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    };
```

Что странно, удаление отрабатывает нормально, а вот пост-запрос блокируется. Я уже не знаю куда копать, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Копать [сюда](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) и [сюда](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) — механизм, использующий
> дополнительные HTTP-заголовки, чтобы дать возможность агенту
> пользователя получать разрешения на доступ к выбранным ресурсам с
> сервера на источнике (домене), отличном от того, что сайт использует в
> данный момент. Говорят, что агент пользователя делает запрос с другого
> источника (cross-origin HTTP request), если источник текущего
> документа отличается от запрашиваемого ресурса доменом, протоколом или
> портом.

> Некоторые запросы не заставляют срабатывать CORS preflight. Они
> называются “простыми запросами” в данной статье, хотя Fetch
> спецификация, определяющая CORS, не использует этот термин. Запрос,
> для которого не срабатывает CORS preflight— так называемый “простой
> запросы”—это запрос, удовлетворяющий следующим условиям:

Допустимые методы для запроса:
GET
HEAD
POST

Далее для настройки [Asp.Net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942037/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader();
    }));

    // ...
}

[EnableCors("MyPolicy")]


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCors("MyPolicy");

    // ...

    // This should always be called last to ensure that
    // middleware is registered in the correct order.
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: Этот вариант я уже пробовал - безуспешно, та же реакция

Comment: В любом случае вам нужно правильно ответить на CORS preflight